# "Go XXX" or "go to XXX"

Tags: word-choice, differences, prepositions

Sometimes I see *go XXX* (*go home*) and sometimes *go to XXX* (*go to school*, *go to work*). Is there any specific rule about this?

Comment: @Jasper Loy: I was totally distracted by the use of *somewhere* without the delimiters <>, taking it literally. Now when I check the original, I feel the original conveyed the OP's intention better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When *go* is followed by a noun, it needs *to*.  When it's followed by anything else, it doesn't. (In 'go home', *home* is an adverb.)

Comment: I expected this answer to be challenged. I'd be grateful if the down-voter would do so, perhaps by producing counter-examples.

Comment: So I should wait for more answers, right?

Comment: @W.N.: Some words may not immediately appear to be nouns and therefore seem to conflict: *Go fishing*/ *Go shopping*. In reality, I do not see any conflict here, though.

Comment: Barrie, I have posted numerous comments seeking out the fly-by down voters. Someone should post a question on meta and try to solve this.

Comment: @Kris: [Encouraging people to explain down-votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)

Comment: Agree, I saw your post point was 3, now it's 2, so someone must have vote you down. I hate those lazy people!

Comment: Okay, I'll challenge you, even though I'm not the downvoter. In most American cities, you can *go downtown,* although Ngrams shows this isn't used much in British English. (You could also classify the word *home* in *go home* not as a noun but a directional adverb. You can *go home, walk home*, or *head home*, just the same way you *go west, walk downstairs*, or *head downtown*.)

Comment: @PeterShor: "Downtown" is listed as an adverb (which is how I understand it in your example) as well as an adjective and a noun (Oxford Dictionaries Online). It doesn't exactly deviate from the rule that Barrie has given. As for "home", the same source lists it as an adverb, too.

Comment: @Irene: I shoiuld have been more explicit. I haved edited my answer to make it so.

Comment: *Go fly a kite!*

Comment: Sorry I haven't challenged this before, Barry – I've only just found it. I don't like the classification of 'home' when non-nounal as an intransitive preposition. However, 'Is John home yet?' argues strongly against the adverb classification. I stick with locative / directional particle. // The oddness of the behaviour of _home_ is because there are essentially two words, 'home', and 'to/at-home' which has assumed the same form.